# Curvature of the sine curve using arc length?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm reading [Toward a living soft microrobot through optogenetic locomotion control of Caenorhabditis elegans](https://robotics.sciencemag.org/content/6/55/eabe3950.full)

The problem is as follows, which is Equation (1) of the paper on page 5 of 14.

$$
\kappa(s)=-\frac{2 \pi \rho}{L} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{L}(s-v t)\right), s \in[0, l]
\tag{1}
$$
where $\kappa$ is the curvature, $s$ is the arc length, $v$ is the tangential speed of the worm, $u$ is the speed of the scanning laser patterns along the worm centerline, $L$ is the undulation wavelength, $l$ is the total body length, $\rho$ is the undulation angle of attack.

**We want to deduce (or check) Equation (1) in the paper.**

To simplify the problem, we set $t=0$, and $l=L$ (considering the energy released within one undulation wavelength $L$; see lines 1-2 on left column of Page 6). Then (1) is converted to
$$
\kappa(s)=-\frac{2 \pi \rho}{L} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{L}s\right), s \in[0, L]
\tag{1'}
$$

Since $\cos(x+\pi/2)=-\sin x$ and $\cos(x-\pi/2)=\sin x$, without loss of generality, we can also consider  a  following equation (2) that substitutes for (1')
$$
\kappa(s)=-\frac{2 \pi \rho}{L} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{L}s\right), s \in[0, L]
\tag{2}
$$
Noting that $\kappa(s) = d\theta/ds$, we have
$$
\theta = \rho \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{L}s\right), \quad 0\leq s\leq L
\tag{3}
$$
where $\theta$ is the tangent angle of the sine curve (between the slope line and the horizontal line), and we also assume in (3) that $\rho$ is the maximum of $\theta$ (in fact $\rho=\frac{\pi}{4}$), and $L$ is the total length of sine curve over $[0, 2\pi]$.

Since $L$ is the total length of sine curve over $[0, 2\pi]$, for the sine curve $y=\sin(x)$ we have
$$
L=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sqrt{1+\cos ^{2}(x)} d x=\sqrt{2} E\left(2\pi,\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx 7.640
$$
where $E(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the complete Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind that can be computed using [the Carlson package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Carlson/index.html) in R   as `L = sqrt(2)*Carlson::elliptic_E(2*pi, 1/2)`. We also have the arc length $s$ as
$$
s=s(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+\cos ^{2}(u)} d u
$$
**We want to show that (3) is correct. Then we may probably verify Equation (1) in the paper.**

For a plane curve given by the equation $y=f(x)$, the curvature at a point $M(x, y)$ is expressed in terms of the first and second derivatives of the function $f(x)$ by the formula
$$
\kappa=\frac{\left|y^{\prime \prime}(x)\right|}{\left[1+\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)^{2}\right]^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
which implies for the sine curve that
$$
\kappa=\frac{|\sin (x)|}{\left(1+\cos ^{2}(x)\right)^{3 / 2}}
\tag{4}
$$

**I tried to prove the equivalence of (2) and (4), i.e., expressing the curvature of the sine curve via the arc length $s$,  but failed. Furthermore,  If (2) and (4) are equivalent, can we say (3) is correct?**

BTW,  we note that $\tan(\theta)=\cos(x)$ for $y=\sin(x)$ because corresponding derivative $d\sin(x)/dx=\cos(x)$. Then we can  verify the following facts via  [R](https://www.r-project.org/)   (Python, Octave or Julia) numerically

```
s_fun = function(x){
  s = sqrt(2)*Carlson::elliptic_E(x, 1/2)
  s
}

theta1 = function(x){
  # tan(theta) = cos(x) for sin(x) as dsin(x)/dx=cos(x)
  theta = atan(cos(x))
  theta
}

theta2 = function(s,rho=pi/4){
  L = sqrt(2)*Carlson::elliptic_E(2*pi, 1/2)
  theta = rho*cos(s*2*pi/L)
  theta
}

x = c(0,1,pi/2,2,3,pi,4,pi*3/2,5,6,2*pi)  # x ∈ [0,2Π]
t1 = theta1(x) # θ by tan(theta) = cos(x)
t2 = sapply(x,function(x) theta2(s_fun(x))) # θ by (3) above
cbind(t1,t2)
```

which gives

```
                   t1               t2
 [1,]  7.853982e-01+0i  7.853982e-01+0i  # x = 0  ---> θ = pi/4 ≈ 0.7853982
 [2,]  4.953673e-01+0i  3.712309e-01+0i  # x = 1
 [3,]  6.123032e-17+0i  4.809018e-17+0i  # x = pi/2 ---> θ = 0
 [4,] -3.943481e-01+0i -2.789878e-01+0i  # x = 2
 [5,] -7.803693e-01+0i -7.748087e-01+0i  # x = 3
 [6,] -7.853982e-01+0i -7.853982e-01+0i  # x = pi ---> θ = -pi/4 ≈ -0.7853982
 [7,] -5.789324e-01+0i -4.614580e-01+0i  # x = 4
 [8,] -1.836910e-16+0i -8.418442e-16+0i  # x = pi*3/2 ---> θ = 0 
 [9,]  2.764014e-01+0i  1.864550e-01+0i  # x = 5
[10,]  7.650814e-01+0i  7.437384e-01+0i  # x = 6
[11,]  7.853982e-01+0i  7.853982e-01+0i  # x = 2*pi ---> θ = pi/4 ≈ 0.7853982
```

showing that the answer we want to prove is NO (although $\theta$ coincides on certain $x$ points).  **Did I miss or misunderstanding something  for check Equation (1) in the paper?**